# how to find getjson data length in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm populating a drop down with JSON data from getJSON.

Populating is working fine, but trying to find `data1` length by using `data1.length` in alert but am getting `undefined`.

How to find `data1` length. what is wrong in my code?

My code looks like:

```
$.getJSON('/empcodes', function(data1) {
    $selectmercode.html('');
    $selectmercode.append('<option>' + "--Select--" + '</option>');
    alert(data1.length);
    $.each(data1.data, function(key, val) {
        $selectmercode.append('<option id=' + val.id + '>' + val.code + '</option>');
    })
});
```

Comment: You're aware of the typo right? `alert(data1.legth);`

Comment: @Reddog: Yes, it is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data1.length` returns undefined because it is an object, not an array.

You should instead get value of `data1.data.length` which as i suppose is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

`data1` is an object which doesn't have `length` property thus you are getting `undefined`.

And, I think you need to check the `length` of `data1.data`. So use

```
console.log(data1.data.length);
```

```js
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.length)

var obj2 = new Object();
console.log(obj2.length)
```